# Pi in openmp not depends on threads

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, montecarlo

I have a problem with OpenMp. I need to compute Pi with OpenMP and Monte Carlo. I write simple program and i am reading number of threads from command line. Now it is working not stable sometimes 1 thread is faster than 16. Have anyine idea what am i doing wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
int niter, watki;
watki = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
niter = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);
intcount=0                                                                          
int i;
double x, y, z;
double pi;
omp_set_dynamic(0);  
unsigned int myseed = omp_get_thread_num();
double start = omp_get_wtime();
omp_set_num_threads(watki);
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,x,y,z) reduction(+:count)
  for ( i=0; i<niter; i++) {                                                                              
    x = (double)rand_r(&myseed)/RAND_MAX;                                                                          
    y = (double)rand_r(&myseed)/RAND_MAX;                                                                          
    z = x*x+y*y;                                                                                          
    if (z<=1) count++;                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                      
pi=(double)count/           niter*4;                                                                                   
printf("# of trials= %d, threads %d , estimate of pi is %g \n",niter, watki,pi); 
double end = omp_get_wtime();
printf("%f \n", (end - start));
}
```

I compile it with gcc -fopenmp pi.c -o pi
And run it with ./pi 1 10000
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `omp_get_thread_num` outside of the parallel region, which will always return 0.

Then all your `rand_r` calls will access the same shared seed, which is probably the source of your problem. You should declar `myseed` within the loop to make it private to each thread, and to get the correct value from `omp_get_thread_num`

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,x,y,z) reduction(+:count)
for ( i=0; i<niter; i++) {
  int myseed = omp_get_thread_num();
  x = (double)rand_r(&myseed)/RAND_MAX;               
  y = (double)rand_r(&myseed)/RAND_MAX;               
  z = x*x+y*y;      
  if (z<=1) count++;  
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if i good understand. I need to create one more section and put into it setthreads and then pragma with for?

Comment: i've edited my answer to include an example of what I was suggesting

Comment: Thank You very much. It is hard to tell why it did not work before cause as i remember i used to try in this way... ;) Thanks.